# Alternatives to error-first pattern and promises, in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

In nodejs, when you call an asynch function using the error-first pattern, even if you can't handle the error at the level of the current function and just want to transmit it to the upper one, you have to write this :

```
var myAsyncFunc = function (callback) {
    doStuff();
    doAsyncStuff(function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            callback(err);
            return;
        }
        res = doSomeOtherStuff(res);
        callback(null, res);
    });
};
```

The 4 lines "if (err) ..." are the there to say "I can't handle the error here, so I just propagate it".
For me, this look really not an elegant way to handle errors. It's like if in a synchronous code I had to do this:

```
void mySyncFunc() {
    doStuff();
    try {
        int res = doSyncStuff();
        return doSomeOtherSuff(res);
    } catch (SomeException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

This would be horrible, and I'm happy to be able to just write:

```
void mySuncFunc() throws SomeException {
    doStuff();
    int res = doSyncStuff();
    return doSomeOtherStuff(res);
}
```

And before someone says it, async.series don't change this problem (it only allows less nesting, but you still have to do the if(err) part).

Promises allow to write more compact and elegant code. But they still add a big layer to the language, and most of the nodejs modules don't use those.

My questions are :

- without using promises & es6, is there another pattern than the error-first to write more compact code (I suppose not, because I already searched a lot... but I want to be sure)
- why is there so much code using this clutter way of propagating the error ; and no one seems to find this tiring, even after years of using synchronous languages where this is so easy? Am I totally missing an important point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reactive Extensions**

There is one alternative I can think of, you don't already mentioned: [Reactive Extensions](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/callbacks.md). But much like promises it adds a layer of abstraction to the callback, which lets you handle errors at the end of an operator chain:

```
var observedAsyncFunc = Rx.Observable.fromCallback(asyncFunc);
```

This returns a function, which you can run and optionally put parameters in (which are expected by asyncFunc)

```
var source = observedAsyncFunc(); //this "runs" the asyncFunc (/returns the observable)
```

now start "operating" (in this example the result is just multiplied with itself):

```
source
    .map(result => result * result)
    //...
```

... and finally, when you're finished operating, subscribe to the observable, where you can act on the result and handle errors:

```
source
    .map(result => result * result)
    .subscribe(
        result => console.log("we got something "+result),
        error => console.log("ERROR"),
        () => console.log("observable completed")
    );
```

**Promises**

I know you wrote, you don't want to hear anything about any promise nonsense, but you also wrote you have a problem with a lot of node modules don't implementing promises. That's actually not really a problem, because (given the async functions in the node module comply to the standard callback pattern) you can [`promisify()`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) the function to make it return a promise. If you use [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) for example, you can:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var promisifiedAsyncFunc = Promise.promisify(asyncFunc);

promisifiedAsyncFunc()
    .then(function(res){/*...*/})
    .catch(function(err){/*...*/});
```

Comment: Thank's for your detailed answer. RE seems interesting, but feels like it has the same advantages as Promises, and isn't standard in ES6 ; so there may not be much point to using it. By the way, I didn't want to say promises were nonsense ! There are really good. It's juste that using them with libs instead of having them in the language like in ES6 is a big problem, and make them way less nice to use.

Comment: You're right, Rx observables can be used to simulate promise functionality (like I did in the answer) and they behave very much like promises if you do so, but that's the point, right? Observables can do much more, but that's not in the scope of this question. To the language statement: I thought that promises unlike observables [are part of ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-promise-objects).